# Is there any algorithm suitable for compression of GPS waypoints?

Tags: floating-point, gps, compression, coordinates, gpx

I am looking for any algorithm for lossy compression of GPS track waypoints with coordinates in `EPSG:4326 CRS` *(this usual degrees like (75.223423,-10.123123))*

For short, *after wiping out meta information and simplification with Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm,* I have an ordered sequence of waypoint coordinates, each waypoint takes 16 bytes (2 x 8-byte `double`).

Using the knowledge that waypoints are ordered, and the distance between waypoints in most cases is less than 0.01° (*~1 km at equator*), I made an assumption, that there may be some kind of lossy compression algorithm for such sequences.

Could you help me find it out, please.

**UPD:** According to real tracks (~800 analyzed), the distance in degrees between points is shown below. P95 is 95th percentile of all distances.

```
LON    
    avg: 0,000334560520818109
    p95: 0,001239999999999240 # ~138 meters
    max: 0,307273900000000000
LAT    
    avg: 0,000221987685948093
    p95: 0,000839999999996621
    max: 0,309625799999999000
```

Comment: Try first common generic lossless compression tools on your data set to assess the potential compression factor possible.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think that usual compression methods are optimized for repeated sequences and vocabulary usage. In my case, no vocabulary or repeated sequences exist in binary form, so it gives too small compression rate with too high resource usage ( cpu and ram ).

Comment: "In my case, no vocabulary or repeated sequences exist in binary form" is contradicted by " distance between waypoints in most cases is less than 0.01°" --> There is a pattern to your data.  " too high resource usage" is not part of the post.  If you have restrictions, best to clarify them in the post.  " gives too small compression rate" --> What was that rate?

Comment: It's 35% only at `Optimal` GZip and Deflate. Better on `Optimal` Brotli ( 21.5% avg ). Measured for 5000 real GPX files. I think it is still quite big and loseless.

I'll try experiment combining float upscaling to integers (lossy) and compressing it with default algorythms.


*** `Optimal` is terms of .net.

Comment: The acceptable amount of "lossy" is up to you.  What is your estimate of accuracy needed?  To the meter? mm? deca-meter?

Comment: I think 10m is quite good accuracy for my needs.

Comment: A given waypoint, at most, log2(40,075,000m/10m) or 22 bit integer for longitude and 21 for latitude needed.  One piece of info still needed: What is the typical max delta of waypoints?  I recommend to append 2-3 sample sets of maybe 100 waypoint data.  (Each double as %a, we known real data is binary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an existing solution: There is [`TinyWKB` or `TWKB` or `Tiny Well-known Binary`](https://github.com/TWKB/Specification) data format suits my needs.

- It stores geometry primitives (it has `LineString` support for my current needs).
- It stores data using deltas.
- It supports precision for floating points (+2 to -2).
- It supports ID-data for geometries.
- It can be written using .Net module for [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.TinyWKB).

TinyWKB is developed from `WKT -> WKB -> TWKB` to store geometry primitives (Points, LineStrings, Polygons, MultiPoints, MultiLineStrings, MultiPolygons, GeometryCollections)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an eight-byte floating point format for the number of significant figures you expect, and for the limited range of possible values. I would start by converting the data to a sequence of integers of appropriate length that can represent the accuracy and range of your values. It looks like two four-byte integers should suffice. There's a factor-of-two compression right there.

Then replace each point with the difference of that point and the previous one, except for the first point. Now the integers should be smaller, allowing for any general purpose lossless compressor to reduce that further. If the differences are only around 0.1°, you could get another factor of two.

That is a simple example, where the prediction for this point is the last point. If your sequence of points represent a path, you could do something more sophisticated where you model a velocity. In that case you propagate the last point using the last modeled velocity, and subtract that from the current point.

*Amendment*

I found that the WGS84 reference frame itself is accurate to only 2-5 meters. With three-byte integers, you can get 2.4 meters resolution at the equator. That provides a 62.5% reduction, before differencing and compression. It also gives you a free bit in the latitude, since it has half the range of a longitude. That bit could be used to mark whether this is an absolute coordinate or predicted from the last coordinate.

Comment: Well, that idea is useful, but I am afraid of reinventing the wheel. I hope that such kind of compression has already been invented and tested. Like, based on two deltas, or based on angle and distance between two points, and with `keyframes` for non-standard cases, and adopting to actual delta between points, etc, etc.

Comment: I am not aware of an existing implementation. The conversion and subtraction are quite simple for just lat-lat and long-long, and you can rely on off-the-shelf software for the compression part.

Comment: Watch out for crossing 180E->180W. The way points could be metres apart, but ~360 degrees in longitude!

Comment: @dmuir Unless the path is hanging out right on that line, going back and forth across it, then a crossing will have very little impact on the compression.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to write the code yourself, here's a trick for a simple 'delta' encoding scheme that avoids losing accuracy unnecessarily.

The idea is that the compressor should compute deltas NOT between the current data point and the last, but between the current data point and what the decompressor will have computed for the last. This means that the quantisation errors will not add up.

As a simple example that you might want to peruse/experiment with here's c code that compresses doubles into a (start double) and a sequence of floats:

```
typedef struct
{   double  start;
    int n;
    float*  delta;
} compT;

compT   compress( int n, const double* data)
{
compT   c = (compT){ data[0], n-1, malloc( (n-1)*sizeof *c.delta)};
double  r = c.start;
    for( int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    {
    float   d = (float)(data[i]-r);
        c.delta[i-1] = d;
        r += d;
    }
    return c;
}

static  double* uncompress( compT c)
{
double* d = malloc( (c.n+1)*sizeof *d);
double  r = c.start;
    d[0] = r;
    for( int i=1; i<=c.n; ++i)
    {   r += c.delta[i-1];
        d[i] = r;
    }
    return d;
}
compT   bad_compress( int n, const double* data)
{
compT   c = (compT){ data[0], n-1, malloc( (n-1)*sizeof *c.delta)};
    for( int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    {
    float   d = (float)(data[i]-data[i-1]);
        c.delta[i-1] = d;
    }
    return c;
}
```

When using floats the quantization error build up is really only noticeable on long (millions) data sequences.

However when hoping to compress more, the effects are more noticeable. The code below uses an int_16t for the deltas. I've used this in cases where the data values were guaranteed to be around 1Km, so I used a scale (in the code below) of 16, so could cope with differences of 2km.

```
typedef struct
{   float   scale;
    double  start;
    int n;
    int16_t*    delta;
} compiT;

compiT  compressi( int n, const double* data, float scale)
{
compiT  c = (compiT){ scale, data[0], n-1, malloc( (n-1)*sizeof *c.delta)};
double  r = c.start;
    for( int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    {
    int16_t d = (int16_t)round(c.scale*(data[i]-r));
        c.delta[i-1] = d;
        r += ((double)d)/c.scale;
    }
    return c;
}

compiT  bad_compressi( int n, const double* data, float scale)
{
compiT  c = (compiT){ scale, data[0], n-1, malloc( (n-1)*sizeof *c.delta)};
    for( int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    {
    int16_t d = (int16_t)round(c.scale*(data[i]-data[i-1]));
        c.delta[i-1] = d;
    }
    return c;
}

static  double* uncompressi( compiT c)
{
double* d = malloc( (c.n+1)*sizeof *d);
double  r = c.start;
    d[0] = r;
    for( int i=1; i<=c.n; ++i)
    {
    double  delta = ((double)c.delta[i-1])/c.scale;
        r += delta;
        d[i] = r;
    }
    return d;
}
```

In runs of arbitrary length, the maximum error (ie the differences between the original data and the decompressed compressed data) was, as it should be, around 3cm, whereas using the bad_compressor the errors were around 0.5m on runs of 1000, 2.5m on runs of 10000

Of course where you have no guarantees of boundedness of the differences, you'll need to incorporate some sort of restart.

Comment: "This means that the quantisation errors will not add up." --> Good idea.

Comment: In my specific case I found it by adding two types of frames in sequence - _key frames_ and _delta frames_. If distance between computed point and real point is too far from original point, _key frame_ is written, otherwise, lossy _delta frame_ is written. So total quantisation error can not exceed maximum error I set as parameter.